# Android - Export a program to an apk file

Tags: android

Hi
Suppose I have written a litter program in Eclipse, how can I export it to an apk file so as to transfer to my HTC Desire for testing?

Thanks

Comment: As evilone suggest you can just run the build live directly to your HTC Desire over usb. This will allow you write to the Log.d window in Eclipse while running/testing the program on your phone. This will place an apk signed with the debug key on your phone. If you export and use your key, then you can transfer a properly signed apk using the adb command line tool to your phone. TIP: you will not be allowed to download the properly signed apk to your phone from the Android Market if you have a debug signed version on your phone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right click on your project and click Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package or Export Unsigned Application Package.

If you choose signed package then you need to create a keystore. If you choose unsigned package, then you need to enable "Unknown sources" option from your phone in Settings->Applications menu.

Also you can use your phone as an emulator by connecting your phone to computer with USB.

Additional reading: [Signing your applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) and [How to enable USB debugging on your Android phone](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/mobile/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-android-phone/)

Answer (score 1):

Once you run it on your android emulator it will automatically converted to .apk

Comment: Or, if you hate the emulator as much as I do, "Project -> Build Project"

Comment: @Geobits: actually running in emulator includes this task.

Comment: True, but if you don't use the emulator, it's a lot quicker just to build the project and copy it over to the device.