# How to convert from my android project to .apk file?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am beginner in android. I am successfully created one application. In that application name is Hello. It's successfully running in My Emulator. My questions are How to convert that application to .apk files. Because how to i run this application(Hello) to my android tablet. If it is possible please send information for how to convert taht application to .apk format. Otherwise if it is not possible send Reason. Please reply your answers and comments are valuable me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse for developing the android?

Comment: If your means, how to get the apk file of your android project, you can go to `<workspace>/<project-directory>/bin/` and see the *.apk file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Export a program to an apk file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166149/android-export-a-program-to-an-apk-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you don't want to publish your app for now,and just want to get it working on your phone, then you just have to copy the yourApp.apk file from /workspace/yourProject/bin directory to your sdcard and then install it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply try below existing answers -

1. [Export Android .apk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6166192/940096)
2. [.Apk file From application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4853025/940096)
3. [exporting-a-signed-android-package](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/exporting-a-signed-android-package.html)

---

### Steps to Export an .apk

1. Right click your project -> Select Android tools -> Export Signed application package -> Next
2. Choose create new keystore -> set the new location using browse -> and give new name for key also
3. give the password & confirm the password also -> Next
4. Give alias name -> give new or old password & confirm the password also -> fill validity -> and below make one column to fill -> Next
5. set the .apk file's destination to existing location or new location -> Finish

Answer (score 1):

from eclipse

refer link

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/exporting-a-signed-android-package.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

On the main menu, choose Tools | Android | Export Signed Android Package. The Export Signed Android Package Wizard starts.

from command line :

http://asantoso.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/how-to-build-android-application-package-apk-from-the-command-line-using-the-sdk-tools-continuously-integrated-using-cruisecontrol/

even it is also important to know about signing

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1):

Rightclick your project in Eclipse -> Export -> Android -> Export Android Application -> Next -> Create new keystore -> Enter infos -> Follow remaining steps

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does that for you (if you are only looking ot test it on your device rather than actually create an .apk, which is what it sounds like you really want to do).

Simply plug in your device to your computer after you have installed the proper drivers for it and it should show up as a target if you go to Run -> Run Configurations, select your app and then click on the "Target" tab.  Select the device and then you are set to run it on your device from Eclipse.