# Parse Error while installing the apk file

Tags: android, parsing

I've made a calculator app in eclipse targeting an API level 2.3.3. I've mailed it to my mailing address and trying to install it by downloading it. It is giving me the following error

"There is a problem parsing the package."

I am new to android programming. I am using HTC sensation whose android version is 2.3.4.
I am not getting what the problem is. Please help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you signed your App?

Comment: No, How should i do the same?

Comment: There is something Android version problem.

Comment: [Follow this answer's steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11034520/940096)

Comment: If you Sign your App in not proper way you will get this error that why i asked.. Also check if already same signature App is there if so delete it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using gmail as mailing address or any other. From Gmail it will allow to download that file. Also that app in not on android market so before downloading that file you need to check  `settings ==>Applications==> Unknown Sources` check box should be checked and after that download apk file.