# how to create apk from java source code?

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android programming language and I have a question. I would really appreciate if someone guides me in this regard.
I have java source code of an Android project (no entire project). Can I build the application without other required files such as xml file for layout and ....

Regards,
H

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166149/android-export-a-program-to-an-apk-file

Comment: Please have a look at Android's beginner's tutorials. This one might be what you're looking for : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: Make a new project. Then copy the files you have in it. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: Without xml files? No, you cannot. If you want to create an apk file then just run the program on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

First of, an android application is just an "archive" that contains a specific architecture.
As you pointed out, it is composed of a Manifest (xml) file defining the different parts of your application: Activities, Services, Permissions, etc.

There is also the resources files such as layouts, pictures and files used by the application.

Finally, there is the source code.

I recommend you take a look at online tutorials which are well detailed over the Internet, and to take a look at the Android SDK samples.

To develop Android applications, I recommend that you download the Android ADT bundle (containing both Android SDK and Eclipse IDE including Android projects management).